# Flatten a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following column:

```
0          [Joe]
1           John
2           Mary
3         [Joey]
4          Harry
5        [Susan]
6          Kevin
```

I can't seem to remove the `[]` with out making the rows with `[]` = `NaN`

To be clear I want the column to look like this:

```
0            Joe
1           John
2           Mary
3           Joey
4          Harry
5          Susan
6          Kevin
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title seems to imply that some elements of your series are lists.

***setup***

```
s = pd.Series([['Joe'], 'John', 'Mary', ['Joey'], 'Harry', ['Susan'], 'Kevin'])
s

0      [Joe]
1       John
2       Mary
3     [Joey]
4      Harry
5    [Susan]
6      Kevin
dtype: object
```

***option 1***
apply with `pd.Series`

```
s.apply(pd.Series).squeeze()

0      Joe
1     John
2     Mary
3     Joey
4    Harry
5    Susan
6    Kevin
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip("'[]") if type(x) == list else x)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'` I think the lists within the column are causing issues. I need to address the multiple lists of length 1 within the column rather than just strip the `[]`

Comment: Yes that worked! It returned the column with single quotes i.e. `''` where there was previously `[]`. To remove those I added `.strip("''")` to the end of your solution so it ended up working with :

Comment: `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).strip('[]').strip("''"))`

Comment: @firetheRookie Don't have to use an additional strip. You can do that in 1 strip. `strip("'[]")` Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `s.astype(str).str.strip ("'[]'")` 
or

`s.map(lambda x: x if type(x) != list else x [0])`